# The derivative of $h(\phi)=g(\epsilon + f(1-\phi))$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I have a function

$$
h(\phi)=g(\epsilon + f(1-\phi)).
$$

Here, $\epsilon$ is a constant, and $g$ and $f$ (like $h$) are functions of a single variable.  The variable here is $\phi$.

I'm being told that

$$
h'(\phi)=-g'(\epsilon+f(1-\phi))f'(1-\phi).
$$

How does one arrive at this conclusion?  The negative sign is what's confusing me.

If you think it'd be helpful, I'd be happy to share context and/or my work on this (i.e., what I think the derivative should be).  Just ask.

In theory, though, there is enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: Hint: what is the derivative of $f(1-\phi)$?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter i used the chain-rule tag because i know that's required.  but when i apply the chain rule, i get a different answer.  obviously i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @David the answer has it: $f'(1-\phi)$.  it's not broken down any farther than that.  i still don't see how the negative pops out in the solution stated in the question.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter The accepted convention on this site is that one should not edit the OP's notation unless it is actually wrong.

Comment: @dbliss His point is that you have to apply the chain rule to $f(1-\phi)$.

Comment: @dbliss That's not correct.  This is where your error is.  To differentiate $f(1-\phi)$ you should use the chain rule.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter got it -- nested chain rule.

Comment: @dbliss this is where the negative comes from. David, apologies